# C# How to Hide PowerShell Window

Tags: c#, powershell

I have met a problem using PowerShell command in a WPF app. The basic requirement here is PowerShell should run in the background without popping up any console window.

However, if I create a RunSpace and run the command in the Pipeline, I can't hide the console window at all. Following is my codes:

```
private void RunAppCapture()
{
    var initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    initial.ImportPSModule(new[] { "vmware.appcapture" });

    var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
    runSpace.Open();

    Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

    Command capture = new Command("Start-AVAppCapture");
    capture.Parameters.Add("Name", "Test");
    pipeline.Commands.Add(capture);

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    pipeline.Invoke();
    if (pipeline.Error.Count > 0)
    {
        while (!pipeline.Error.EndOfPipeline)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(pipeline.Error.Read().ToString());
        }
    }
    runSpace.Close();

    try
    {
        Result.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Result.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

The only way to hide the window is to run the PowerShell in a process. However, by doing so, I can't reuse the context because I have launch a brand-new PowerShell process every time. Here is my codes:

```
private void RunPowerShellProcess()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process p = new Process();

    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.Arguments = "import-module vmware.appcapture;Start-AVAppCapture -Name Test";
    startInfo.FileName = "Powershell.exe";

    p.StartInfo = startInfo;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
    (
        delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(output.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    );
    p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler
    (
        delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamReader output = p.StandardError)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(output.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    );


    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();

    string finalStdOuputLine = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string finalStdErrorLine = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    try
    {
        Result.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Result.Text = String.Format("Result: {0}, Error: {1}", finalStdOuputLine, finalStdErrorLine);
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

I really would like to use RunSpace. But how can I on the one hand reuse a PowerShell context, but on the other hand hide the console window?

Comment: have your tried using the following `StartInfo.WindowStyle =.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`

Comment: In my second codes snippet, I used the process to hide the PowerShell window. However, I don't like this method, because I can't reuse a PowerShell context. For instance, I have to import the module everytime running the command. However, by using RunSpace, I can reuse a context. But the problem with RunSpace is that I can't hide the window. Hence, I'm asking if any expert knows it?

Answer (score 1):

I created a console app with the following and experienced no powershell windows visible at all. I routinely use the RunSpace and RunSpacePool classes and have never experienced a powershell instance becoming visible.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initial.ImportPSModule(new[] { "BITSTransfer" });

        var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
        runSpace.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            using (Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline())
            {
                Command capture = new Command("Get-Command");
                capture.Parameters.Add("Module", "BITSTransfer");
                pipeline.Commands.Add(capture);
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("In loop {0}", i));
                    System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject> outputCollection = pipeline.Invoke();
                    foreach (PSObject item in outputCollection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        runSpace.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

As you can see this creates a runspace and imports a module. It then creates a pipeline and writes the commands in that module to screen 5 times. Each time using the same runspace. No powershell windows were spawned.

I'm not sure what this is doing though, nor am I sure if its responsible for spawning the window you reference.

```
 Result.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Result.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
    }));
```